# AngularJS ng-grid progressbar when loading data

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, ng-grid

I have an angular ng-grid table, with a large amount of data. I don't know about REST API's, so my data source is from a PHP controller that sends the data via JSON. Some of my data requires source from a few external API's, so on every record loop, I use curl to get the data from the external API.

This cause heavy loading time. And it can't be helped. But what I can do is put a progressbar while the data loads. Is there a way to do it via angular?? or any other way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Angular Loading Bar](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/). It automates the loading bar's progress, by using angular interceptors. Multiple requests within the same time period get bundled together such that each response increments the progress bar by the appropriate amount. I think this is what you need